# Make query with subselects faster

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, subquery

I have the following stored procedure that when run without the subselects, is ultra fast. However i need the results from those subselects to get info i need. Is there another way to obtain those results without the need for those subqueries, or is there any way to make those subqueries more optimized?

```
USE [macal]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[APsp_MapaClientesSemanaUmCliente]    Script Date: 26/02/2016 10:56:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[APsp_MapaClientesSemanaUmCliente] 

@Vendedor varchar(20) = '',
@NoCliente int = 0,
@NoEstab int = 0

AS 


DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
set @ColumnName =   STUFF((
                select ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
                --+',' 
                + QUOTENAME(courses.anomes)
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 'S'+ltrim(rtrim(str(ft.ftano)))+right('0'+ltrim(rtrim(str(datepart(week,ft.fdata)))),2) anomes,row_number() over (order by 'S'+ltrim(rtrim(str(ft.ftano)))+right('0'+ltrim(rtrim(str(datepart(week,ft.fdata)))),2)) row FROM ft where ft.fdata >= DATEADD(week,-11, GETDATE()) 
                group by 'S'+ltrim(rtrim(str(ft.ftano)))+right('0'+ltrim(rtrim(str(datepart(week,ft.fdata)))),2)
                ) Courses

                FOR XML PATH('')
                ),1,1,'');

        --      print @columnname

DECLARE @ColumnNameSelect AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @ColumnNameSelect = STUFF((
SELECT
',ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(courses.anomes)+',0) AS '+QUOTENAME('S'+ltrim(rtrim(str(courses.row))))
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT 'S'+ltrim(rtrim(str(ft.ftano)))+right('0'+ltrim(rtrim(str(datepart(week,ft.fdata)))),2) anomes,row_number() over (order by 'S'+ltrim(rtrim(str(ft.ftano)))+right('0'+ltrim(rtrim(str(datepart(week,ft.fdata)))),2)) row FROM ft where ft.fdata >= DATEADD(week,-11, GETDATE())  
group by 'S'+ltrim(rtrim(str(ft.ftano)))+right('0'+ltrim(rtrim(str(datepart(week,ft.fdata)))),2)
) Courses
order by anomes
FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'');

 --print @columnnameselect

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT 
nome,
no,
estab,
morada,
telefone,
tlmvl,
contacto,
email,
ZonaVenda,
ZonaDist,
segmento,
classe,
descpp,
esaldo,
plafondseg,
pmr,
ref,
design,
unidade,
uni2,
peso,
u_uncx,
PrecoTab,
Desc1,
Desc2,
Desc4,
Preco,
DataPreco,
media_semana,

' + @ColumnNameSelect + '

FROM 
(
select cl.nome,
ft.no,
ft.estab,
cl.morada,
cl.telefone,
cl.tlmvl,
cl.contacto,
cl.email,
cl.zona ZonaVenda,
cl.u_zonav ZonaDist,
cl.segmento,
cl.classe,
cl.descpp,
cl.esaldo,
cl.U_EPLAFSEG plafondseg,
ltrim(rtrim(str((select
case 
when count(re.restamp) <> 0 then isnull(sum(datediff(dd,cc.datalc,re.procdata)),0) / count(re.restamp) else 0 end 
from    rl (nolock) 
inner   join re (nolock) on re.restamp = rl.restamp 
inner   join cc (nolock) on cc.ccstamp = rl.ccstamp  
inner   join cl (nolock) on cl.no = cc.no 
where cl.no=ft.no and cl.estab=ft.estab and 
re.process = 1 and 
re.procdata >= convert(char(8), dateadd(mm, -12, getdate()), 112)
)))) PMR,
fi.ref,
st.design,
st.unidade,
st.uni2,
st.peso,
st.u_uncx,
isnull((select top 1 fix.epv from fi(nolock) fix,ft(nolock) ftx where fix.ftstamp=ftx.ftstamp and fix.ref=fi.ref and fix.etiliquido>0 and ftx.no=ft.no and ftx.estab=ft.estab and ftx.tipodoc=1 order by ftx.fdata desc,ftx.fno desc),0) PrecoTab,
isnull((select top 1 fix.desconto from fi(nolock) fix,ft(nolock) ftx where fix.ftstamp=ftx.ftstamp and fix.ref=fi.ref and fix.etiliquido>0 and ftx.no=ft.no and ftx.estab=ft.estab and ftx.tipodoc=1 order by ftx.fdata desc,ftx.fno desc),0) Desc1,
isnull((select top 1 fix.desc2 from fi(nolock) fix,ft(nolock) ftx where fix.ftstamp=ftx.ftstamp and fix.ref=fi.ref and fix.etiliquido>0 and ftx.no=ft.no and ftx.estab=ft.estab and ftx.tipodoc=1 order by ftx.fdata desc,ftx.fno desc),0) Desc2,
isnull((select top 1 fix.desc4 from fi(nolock) fix,ft(nolock) ftx where fix.ftstamp=ftx.ftstamp and fix.ref=fi.ref and fix.etiliquido>0 and ftx.no=ft.no and ftx.estab=ft.estab and ftx.tipodoc=1 order by ftx.fdata desc,ftx.fno desc),0) Desc4,
isnull((select top 1 fix.etiliquido/fix.qtt from fi(nolock) fix,ft(nolock) ftx where fix.ftstamp=ftx.ftstamp and fix.ref=fi.ref and fix.etiliquido>0 and ftx.no=ft.no and ftx.estab=ft.estab and ftx.tipodoc=1 order by ftx.fdata desc,ftx.fno desc),0) Preco,
isnull((select top 1 ftx.fdata from fi(nolock) fix,ft(nolock) ftx where fix.ftstamp=ftx.ftstamp and fix.ref=fi.ref and fix.etiliquido>0 and ftx.no=ft.no and ftx.estab=ft.estab and ftx.tipodoc=1 order by ftx.fdata desc,ftx.fno desc),0) DataPreco,
isnull((select avg(mytable.qtt) from
(
select ftx.no,ftx.estab,fix.ref,datepart(week,ftx.fdata) week,sum(case when ftx.tipodoc=3 then -fix.qtt else fix.qtt end) qtt
from ft(nolock) ftx,fi(nolock) fix where ftx.ftstamp=fix.ftstamp and ftx.no=ft.no and ftx.estab=ft.estab and fix.ref=fi.ref
and ftx.tipodoc=1 and ftx.fdata >= DATEADD(week,-11, GETDATE())
group by ftx.no,ftx.estab,fix.ref,datepart(week,ftx.fdata))
mytable
),0)
media_semana,

''S''+ltrim(rtrim(str(ft.ftano)))+right('+'''0'''+'+ltrim(rtrim(str(datepart(week,ft.fdata)))),2) anomes,
fi.qtt 

from fi,ft,st,cl 
where 
fi.ftstamp=ft.ftstamp and fi.ref=st.ref and cl.no=ft.no and cl.estab=ft.estab 
and ft.fdata >= DATEADD(week,-23, GETDATE())
and ft.tipodoc=1 
and fi.qtt<>0
and cl.no='+cast(@NoCliente as nvarchar(10))+'
and cl.estab='+cast(@NoEstab as nvarchar(10))+'
and cl.vendnm like case when '''+@Vendedor+''' = '+'''TODOS'''+' then '+'''%'''+' else '''+@Vendedor+''' end

) p
PIVOT(SUM(qtt) 
      FOR anomes IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable
      order by ref'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: 9 times out of 10 PIVOT is because people are trying to solve presentation issues in the query. Chances are you could do a lot of the work in a code layer better used for presentation.

Comment: The pivot table works wonders here in terms of speed, so I wouldn't focus on that. Instead I would go with solving the subqueries part.

Comment: At least try Allan's suggestion. Making a query too deep makes it hard for the query optimizer to do its job. Populate the derived table you intend to pivot in a temporary table instead, and pivot on the temporary table. It might improve performance. Other than that, your query is wrong on many levels so the question is a little "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting the sub queries into temp tables or table variables?

Joins are usually very fast but it might be hard depending on how your tables are structured and how many rows are in your datasets.

Comment: The problem is I'm not an expert at tsql even though I've learned a lot of stuff through the years. This query I'm using is based on another post I've had answered a few weeks ago and now I needed a few more variables into it through the use of sub queries where basically I need the latest price, discounts from 1 to 4 and net price from the same table (fi) I'm getting the quantities from. The easiest way I know is through subqueries. How would a join be more efficient? Can you give me an example based on my code?

Comment: Could I use a cte to get those variables from there through a join where I would match the ft.no , ft.estab and the row number being = 1 if I ordered the cte by fdata desc, fno desc? Would it be more efficient?

Comment: I don't use pivot tables all that much.  But I would look at the query execution plan in sql server and determine where the nested loops are.  You should be able to see the difference between the execution plan when not using sub queries and then adding sub queries.    **Joining on sort sounds dangerous, I would only join on a primary and foreign key relationships**

Comment: If you don't have good keys to join on then temp tables probably won't help.

Comment: The ft.no and ft.estab guarantee I get the client I need, the sort by fdata desc, fno desc guarantee I get row number 1 for each client as being the one which has the latest prices and discounts. Makes sense,no?

Comment: I would just be concerned that when you get the top 1 you could be missing something if there are ever 2 rows for the client in your table instead of 1.  I would follow along with the other suggestions in the other comments.